# Php Dependency Injecttion in Zend 2

Tags: php, inheritance, dependency-injection, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have two classes. Lets says it is Album and AlbumManager. Album is a intake class which I am using for generating basic entity function. I  do not want to touch Album for custom functions. All other custom function I wrote in AlbumManager class.

Now from controller, when I try to access Album class through AlbumManager, it through me an error:

> Can not be mapped or accessed.

How can I handle this type of dependency? Here are the classes:

**`Album.php`**

```
<?php

namespace Album\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Album
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="album")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Album
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="artist", type="string", length=255, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    private $artist;
/**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set artist
     *
     * @param string $artist
     * @return Album
     */
    public function setArtist($artist)
    {
        $this->artist = $artist;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get artist
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getArtist()
    {
        return $this->artist;
    }

    ?>
```

**`AlbumManager.php`**

```
<?php

/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

namespace Album\Manager;

use Album\Entity as Album;

use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\InputFilter\Factory as InputFactory;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface; 

class AlbumManager
{
    private $album;
    protected $inputFilter;

    public function __construct(Album\Entity $album)
    {
        $this->album = $album;
    }

    public function getAlbum()
    {
        return $this->album;
    }

    /**
     * Magic getter to expose protected properties.
     *
     * @param string $property
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __get($property) 
    {
        return $this->$property;
    }

    /**
     * Magic setter to save protected properties.
     *
     * @param string $property
     * @param mixed $value
     */
    public function __set($property, $value) 
    {
        $this->$property = $value;
    }

    /**
     * Convert the object to an array.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getArrayCopy() 
    {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }

    /**
     * Populate from an array.
     *
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function populate($data = array()) 
    {
        $this->album->setId($data['id']);
        $this->album->setArtist($data['artist']);
        $this->album->setTitle($data['title']);
    }

    public function setInputFilter(InputFilterInterface $inputFilter)
    {
        throw new \Exception("Not used");
    }

    public function getInputFilter()
    {
        if (!$this->inputFilter) {
            $inputFilter = new InputFilter();

            $factory = new InputFactory();

            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                'name'       => 'id',
                'required'   => true,
                'filters' => array(
                    array('name'    => 'Int'),
                ),
            )));

            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                'name'     => 'artist',
                'required' => true,
                'filters'  => array(
                    array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                        'name'    => 'StringLength',
                        'options' => array(
                            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                            'min'      => 1,
                            'max'      => 100,
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            )));

            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                'name'     => 'title',
                'required' => true,
                'filters'  => array(
                    array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                        'name'    => 'StringLength',
                        'options' => array(
                            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                            'min'      => 1,
                            'max'      => 100,
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            )));

            $this->inputFilter = $inputFilter;        
        }

        return $this->inputFilter;
    } 
}
```

**`AlbumController.php`**

```
<?php

namespace Album\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController,
    Zend\View\Model\ViewModel, 
    Album\Form\AlbumForm,
    Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager,
    Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository,
    Album\Entity\Album,
    Album\Manager\AlbumManager,


class AlbumController extends AbstractActionController
{


    public function addAction()
    {
        $form = new AlbumForm();
        $form->get('submit')->setAttribute('label', 'Add');

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isPost()) {
            $album = new Album();
            $albumManager = new AlbumManager($album);
            $form->setInputFilter($album->getInputFilter());
            $form->setData($request->getPost());
            if ($form->isValid()) { 
                $album->populate($form->getData()); 
                $this->getEntityManager()->persist($album);
                $this->getEntityManager()->flush();

                // Redirect to list of albums
                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album'); 
            }
        }

        return array('form' => $form);
    }
?>
```

See the code at AlbumController

```
 $album = new Album();
 $albumManager = new AlbumManager($album);
 $form->setInputFilter($album->getInputFilter());
 $form->setData($request->getPost());
 if ($form->isValid()) { 
     $album->populate($form->getData());
```

The album object can not get access to the getInputFilter and populate  function which I write down in the Album Repository. I understood this happened because of the dependency injected. But what would be the solution so that I can access the album object, set the form data and also can use the album manger functions?

Comment: `@MappedSuperclass` read the Documentation http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html  You should just extend a base class and add the functionality, instead of wrapping it.  At least if I understand the question.

Comment: I extend the base class and also try to use it in controller. But in $form->setInputFilter($album->getInputFilter()); it only takes album object not Albummanager or it can not set the form

Comment: If you extend Albummanger with a parent of Album, then it is an Album by inheritance,  `class Albummanger extends Album{ ... }`  Type hinting is providing a contract to the Album's API ( interface, public methods ) to guarantee they exist, if it's the parent of a class they must exist.

Comment: ....Then the methods must exist in the child class, and it will pass the type hinting, because it would have inherited those methods from its parent `Album`